# How do I handle authentication state in my react.js frontend in an ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I've recently moved my ASP.Net application from Razor pages to a react frontend. So far I am fairly happy with it, however, at the moment I have a problem I'm having a hard time finding a solution for.

I have finished a login page for my user, and everything works fine with HTTP Cookie authentication and Identity.

However, I have all of this information in the backend currently.

My question would now be, how do I tell my react frontend that the user currently viewing the page is authenticated or not?

Of course every call would be checked in the backend to avoid tinkering in the frontend which is most likely possible, but I'm just concerned about having some information as to what to display for now.

Solutions I came up with so far:

1.) Have at data source which queries the current account from backend for every page, and then taking the information from there.

2.) Adding a variable to every served page in a small script block so my React code can look for that and act accordingly.

3.) Somehow check for the presence of the given authentication cookie. However, I have no idea how valid this approach is.

I would therefore love to have some ideas or commonly used schemes for this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The same way you manage any other data, in a `state`.  After the login ran successfully, just store a Boolean like `isAuth: true`.

Comment: @Sagivb.g That's possible, but I am not trying to have a one page application, I would like to have several redirects to other pages as well

Comment: In this case you'll have 2 options as you already mentioned (in my opinion of course): 1. render a global object for holding that Boolean (in your `cshtml`). 2. initiate login on `componentDidMount` with the cookie. The first approach is less network request but exposing a global object with this kind of data is not ideal. The second approach will force you to make "unnecessary" network request but it's more secured.

Comment: @Sagivb.g In your second option, do you refer to make a call to my backend with the cookie data in order to receive information about the user?

Comment: Yeah, you probably do it once at the root component in `componentDidMount`, or before you even call `ReactDOM.render`. I do it sometimes with signalR